# TBB concurrent_bounded queue in C++ and synchronization

Tags: c++, tbb

I am using TBB concurrent_bounded_queue, as this class allows us to use pop which is blocked if no elements are available. What is the default size of the queue? I also read in a book instead of using concurrent_bounded_queue use parallel_while or pipeline, how these will help us in place of concurrent_bounded queue? can any one pls give an example how paralle_while or pipeline can be used to share data between two threads with synchronization?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The default size is of course zero, i.e. no elements in the queue. But you probably want to know the default capacity (i.e. the bound). The [TBB Reference manual](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/index.htm) says that

> A concurrent_bounded_queue <...> adds the ability to specify a capacity. The default capacity makes the queue practically unbounded.

And source code inspection (src/tbb/concurrent_queue.cpp) gives the following formula for default initialization of capacity:

```
    my_capacity = size_t(-1)/(item_size>1 ? item_size : 2);
```

As for `pipeline` or `parallel_while` (note the latter is deprecated), those are algorithms, not containers, and so **cannot** be used to share data between two threads. But in some cases, use of `pipeline` can replace a thread-based design. For example, a simple producer-consumer scenario may be replaced with a two-stage pipeline in which the first stage produces a piece of data and passes it to the second stage to process (consume).